# Show this function is $\sigma$-additive

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega = (0,1]$, $\mathcal{S}=\{(a, b] : 0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1\}$
Define on $\mathcal{S}$ the function by $\lambda : \mathcal{S} \mapsto[0,1]$ by  $$\lambda(\emptyset)=0, \quad \lambda(a, b]=b-a$$

How to show $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-additive? I can only show that it is finite additive.Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We exploit the Zeno's paradox and the Heine Borel theorem.

Suppose that $\{(a_i,b_i]\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset\mathcal S$ is disjoint and its union equals $(a,b]\in\mathcal S$. We clearly have $\sum_{i\leq N}(b_i-a_i) \leq b-a$ for all $N$, so $\sum_{i}(b_i-a_i) \leq b-a$. To prove the reverse inequality, let $\varepsilon>0$. Define $$a_i'=a_i-2^{-(i+1)}\varepsilon,\ b_i'=b_i+2^{-(i+1)}\varepsilon.$$ The intervals $(a_i',b_i')$ cover the compact interval $[a+\varepsilon,b]$, so finitely many of them, say $(a_1',b_1'),\cdots,(a_n',b_n')$, covers $[a+\varepsilon,b]$, and therefore $b-(a+\varepsilon)\leq\sum_{i\leq n}(b_i'-a_i')$. But now $$\sum_{i\leq n}(b'_i-a_i')\leq\sum _i(b_i-a_i+2^{-i}\varepsilon)\leq\sum_i (b_i-a_i)+\varepsilon,$$so $b-a\le\sum_i(b_i-a_i)+2\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, the claim follows.

Comment: We only know the length of interval $(a,b]$ but otherwises,how can you prove that $b-a\leq\sum_{i\leq n}(b_i'-a_i')$ which involves other type of interval $(x,y)$ and $[x,y]$?

Comment: Sure enough, $\lambda$ is only defined for left half-open intervals, but I presume that you know what the length of an interval is, and it shouldn't be difficult to prove that if *finitely many* open intervals cover an interval, then the total length of the covering interval is at least the length of the interval being covered.

Comment: For $b-(a+\varepsilon)\leq\sum_{i\leq n}(b_i'-a_i')$, I try to prove it like this:
let $b_M = \max\{b_i'\}$, $a_m = \min\{a_i'\}$, then $(a+\varepsilon,b] \subset (a_m, b_M]$,so $b-a-\varepsilon \le b_M - a_m \le \sum_{i\leq n}(b'_i-a_i')$ if we only choose $(a_i' , b_i') \cap [a+\varepsilon,b] \ne \emptyset$. Are I right?

Comment: @Spaceship222 Yes you are, although the argument that is necessary to prove the inequality $b_M-a_m\leq \sum _{i\leq n}(b'_i-a_i')$ is essentially the same as the one for proving $b-a-\varepsilon \leq \sum _{i\leq n}(b'_i-a_i')$. If you know Riemann integral, then you could also integrate the functions $\chi _{[a+\varepsilon, b]}$ and $\sum_{i \leq n} \chi_{(a_i',b_i')}$ to obtain the desired inequality. (Here $\chi_E $ denotes the characteristic function of $E\subset \mathbb R$.)